# idiomatic map join in clojure?

Tags: join, clojure, merge

I hava a data structure that looks like this:

```
(def conf 
  { :devices [{:alias "OSC Sender",
               :name "OSC Sender",
               :ins [{:name "xpos", :type :int, :mutable true}]},
              {:alias "const2", :name "const",
               :outs [{:name "out", :type :int}]}],
    :connections {"const2.out" "OSC Sender.xpos"},
    :layout [{:alias "const2",
              :x 72.12447405329594,
              :y 99.88499298737729},
             {:alias "tick",
              :x 82.5732819074334,
              :y 133.91374474053296},
             {:alias "OSC Sender",
              :x 185.17741935483872,
              :y 113.90322580645162}]})
```

I would like to join maps in `:devices` and `:layout` by key (specifically `:alias`) to enrich the devices with layout information.

Right now I cobbled the following solution:

```
(map (partial reduce merge) (vals (group-by :alias (concat (:devices conf) (:layout conf)))))
```

Is that an idiomatic join or is something else preferable?

Cheers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `join` function from the `clojure.set` namespace:

```
(clojure.set/join (conf :devices) (conf :layout) {:alias :alias})
```

Note that the return value is a set. Omitting the final argument results in a natural join; see `(doc clojure.set/join)` for details.

Comment: marczyk, any idea about outer joins, left,right, n full ?
If I want to keep the dictionary on the left set as it is, if it has no match on the other side ?

Comment: `clojure.set` doesn't provide any outer join functions, but of course one can write one's own. That's a subject for a separate question, though; in fact, one that has been asked before, for example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13009939/outer-join-in-clojure).